# horizontal margins

Tags: formatting

My code:

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}  \usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
 \usepackage{natbib} \usepackage{url} \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{amsmath} \usepackage{graphicx} \graphicspath{{images/}}
 \usepackage{parskip} \usepackage{fancyhdr} \usepackage{vmargin}
 \usepackage{wrapfig} \setmarginsrb{3 cm}{2.5 cm}{3 cm}{2.5 cm}{1
 cm}{1.5 cm}{1 cm}{1.5 cm}
 
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%
 
 \cfoot{} % <============================================== no
 pagenumber
 
 \usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}  \usepackage{enumerate} 
 \newcommand{\quest}[1]{ \vspace{.8cm} \noindent\textbf{Questão #1.  }}
 
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 
 %\usepackage{blindtext} % <======================= to generate dummy
 text
 
 \everymath{\displaystyle}
 
 %%%%%%%% \title{Lista 4}                               % Title \author{\lfloor PLEIAD \rfloor
 \text{ Olimpíadas de Ciências Naturais}}                               % Author
 \date{\today}                                          % Date
 
 \makeatletter \let\thetitle\@title \let\theauthor\@author
 \let\thedate\@date \makeatother
 
 \pagestyle{fancy} \fancyhf{} \rhead{\theauthor} \lhead{\thetitle}
 \cfoot{\thepage}
 
 \begin{document}
 
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 
 
 \newcommand{\opt}[2]{\begin{enumerate}[a) ]  \item #1 \item #2
 \end{enumerate}}
 
 
 \rfoot{\textit{ \resizebox{!}{0.25cm}{Outubro de 2021}}}
 
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 
 \begin{titlepage}  \centering
     \vspace*{0.5 cm}
     \includegraphics[scale = 0.75]{logo.png}\\[1.0 cm] % University Logo
     \textsc{\LARGE \newline\newline    \lfloor \text{PL\resizebox{!}{0.5cm}{\sum}\resizebox{!}{0.5cm}{\Lambda}D}
 \rfloor \text{ Olimpíadas de Ciências Naturais}}\\[2.0 cm] %
 University Name    \textsc{\Large Raciocínio Lógico e Contagem}\\[0.5
 cm]                % Course Code   \rule{\linewidth}{0.2 mm} \\[0.4 cm]    { \huge
 \bfseries \thetitle}\\     \rule{\linewidth}{0.2 mm} \\[1.5 cm]    
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}         \begin{flushleft} \large
            \emph{.:}\\             ..\\            \end{flushleft}             \end{minipage}~
            \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
             
            
            \end{minipage}\\[2 cm]
    
    
 
     
     
         \end{titlepage}
 
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 
 
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 
 \noindent\textbf{quest 1.} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim
 ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
 aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
 
 
 \quest{2}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed
 do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim
 ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
 aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
 
 
 \quest{3} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed
 do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim
 ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
 aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
 
 \quest{4}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed
 do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim
 ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
 aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
 
 
 \end{document}
```

I would like to put this template. How can I put these margins on each question?

[image]

Comment: By "margins" do you mean the horizontal lines shown in your graphic?

Comment: @PeterWilson Yes, horizontal lines on the second page to separate the questions, as shown in the model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had, and still have, some difficulties with your MWE but I think that if you do `\renewcommand{\quest}[1]{\vspace{0.8cm} \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt} \\ noindent\textbf{Questao #1. }}` you will have a rule above a question.

```
% ruleprob.tex  SE 620640

 \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}  \usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
 \usepackage{natbib} \usepackage{url} \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{amsmath} \usepackage{graphicx} \graphicspath{{images/}}
 \usepackage{parskip} \usepackage{fancyhdr} \usepackage{vmargin}
 \usepackage{wrapfig} \setmarginsrb{3 cm}{2.5 cm}{3 cm}{2.5 cm}{1
 cm}{1.5 cm}{1 cm}{1.5 cm}
 
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%
 
 \cfoot{} % <============================================== no
% pagenumber %%% what is this?
 
 \usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}  \usepackage{enumerate} 
 \newcommand{\quest}[1]{ \vspace{.8cm} 
\renewcommand{\quest}[1]{\vspace{0.8cm} \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\\
   \noindent\textbf{Questão #1.  }}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 
 %\usepackage{blindtext} % <======================= to generate dummy
 text
 
 \everymath{\displaystyle}
 
 %%%%%%%% \title{Lista 4}                               % Title \author{\lfloor PLEIAD \rfloor
 \text{ Olimpíadas de Ciências Naturais}}                               % Author
 \date{\today}                                          % Date
 
 \makeatletter \let\thetitle\@title \let\theauthor\@author
 \let\thedate\@date \makeatother
 
 \pagestyle{fancy} \fancyhf{} \rhead{\theauthor} \lhead{\thetitle}
 \cfoot{\thepage}
 
 \begin{document}
 
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 
 
 \newcommand{\opt}[2]{\begin{enumerate}[a) ]  \item #1 \item #2
 \end{enumerate}}
 
 
 \rfoot{\textit{ \resizebox{!}{0.25cm}{Outubro de 2021}}}
 
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 
 \begin{titlepage}  \centering
     \vspace*{0.5 cm}
     \includegraphics[scale = 0.75]{logo.png}\\[1.0 cm] % University Logo
     \textsc{\LARGE \newline\newline    \lfloor \text{PL\resizebox{!}{0.5cm}{\sum}\resizebox{!}{0.5cm}{\Lambda}D}
 \rfloor \text{ Olimpíadas de Ciências Naturais}}\\[2.0 cm] %
 University Name    \textsc{\Large Raciocínio Lógico e Contagem}\\[0.5
 cm]                % Course Code   \rule{\linewidth}{0.2 mm} \\[0.4 cm]    { \huge
 \bfseries \thetitle}\\     \rule{\linewidth}{0.2 mm} \\[1.5 cm]    
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}         \begin{flushleft} \large
            \emph{.:}\\             ..\\            \end{flushleft}             \end{minipage}~
            \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
             
            
            \end{minipage}\\[2 cm]
    
          \end{titlepage}
 
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 
 
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 
 \noindent\textbf{quest 1.} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim
 ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
 aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
 
 
 \quest{2}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed
 do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim
 ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
 aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
 
 
 \quest{3} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed
 do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim
 ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
 aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
 
 \quest{4}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed
 do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim
 ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
 aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
 
 
 \end{document}
```

[image]